# Can someone help me to set up reCAPTCHA server side?

Tags: php, html, recaptcha, mail-form

I'm new to PHP and i am trying to add reCaptcha in a PHP mail form. 
The code is similar to this: 
PHP:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $to = "mymail@gmail.com";
    $subject = "subject";
    $message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n";
    $message .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
    $message .= 'IP: ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\n";
    $message .= 'Message: ' . $_POST['message'];
    $success = mail($to, $subject, $message); }?>`
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
<p>name</p>
<input type="text" name="name" class="contactformimput"/>
<p>email*</p>
<input type="text" name="email" class="contactformimput"/>
<p>number</p>
<input type="text" name="number" class="contactformimput"/>
<p>Messaggio*</p>
<input type="text" name="message" onkeyup="adjust_textarea(this)" class="contactformimput" id="contactformtext">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="__MYPUBBLICKEY__"></div>
<div id="divcontactbutton">
<input type="reset" name="send" value="Resetta" class="button" id="resetmessage"/>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Invia Messaggio" class="button" id="sendmessage"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Would you explain what you are stuck on? It seems the CAPTCHA device is in there - what happens when you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Google's recaptcha easy to use,
very first thing you need to do is register your website on Google recaptcha to do that [GoogleRECAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html)

Once submit, Google will provide you following two information.

- Site key
- Secret key

Integrate it in your site inside head tag use this code

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

To show the widget in your form use this code in your form

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="SITE-KEY"></div>
```

When the form gets submitted to Server, this script will send `g-recaptcha-response` as a POST data. You will need to verify it in order to see whether user has checked the Captcha or not

Php code for checking

```
 if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
    if(!$captcha){
      echo '<h2>Check captcha .</h2>';
      exit;
    }
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=YOUR SECRET KEY&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if($response.success==false)
    {
        //redirect back
    }else
    {
       //your mail code 
    }
```

Comment: Yep but what must I do if i don't want any redirect but only email send?

Comment: have a look at the answer again, also redirect back is when
recaptcha fails @paolo.basso99

Comment: ehm, I have another question because I want add an error message, like this:  echo "<div class=\"emailerror\" id=\"emailnoninviata\"><div><span>♠</span> Email non inviata</div></div>"; in 
//redirect back